# Use "Find and replace" within VBA to replace multiple rows?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I have created a simple code in VBA to hide and show certain columns, but now I want to replace parts of the code in all modules using the "Find and replace" window.

(Please excuse my very low coding knowledge... I just really need this to be solved)

E.g. I have a code:

```
' Hide column "Region"
Range("A:A").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

and want to replace it in all modules with:

```
' Hide column "Region" (INACTIVE)
Range("A:A").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

I try to use the "Find and replace" window in VBA and type in the original code in the "Find what" box, but i only end up with the first row showing in the box:

' Hide column "Region"

How can I type the code in the "Find what" box to search for the whole code? I have tried to type the following in the "Find what" box, using "^p", "<^p>", "\p" and "<\p>", without getting any search results:

' Hide column "Region"^pRange("A:A").Select^pSelection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

' Hide column "Region"<^p>Range("A:A").Select<^p>Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

' Hide column "Region"\pRange("A:A").Select\pSelection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

' Hide column "Region"<\p>Range("A:A").Select<\p>Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

and so forth...

I have succeeded do do this once before, but I cannot remember how i did it! Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: What are you actually trying to find and replace? The only difference I can see is true/false.

Comment: I'm trying to replace the entire three rows, as it occurs several times in many different modules. The only difference is that I add " (INACTIVE)" to the first row and change true/false in the last row.

Comment: Don't think you can do that. You would be better of parametising your sub/function. A workaround might be to paste it into Word.

Comment: Now when you mention it, I think I might have solved it last time by extracting the code to Word and do the Find and replace there before replacing the code in VBA with the new one... I'll try it again - big THANKS!

Comment: A better way to do this as SJR suggested is to just create two subroutines in a single module. One to set to true and the the other to set to false. name them "HideMe" and "ShowMe" and then you can just call them from any other module whenever you want to.

Comment: And by avoiding Select you can reduce your code to a single line.

Comment: I just learned how to call a subroutine, which made it A LOT easier to make small changes in the code in the future, thanks SJR and John Wilson!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by copying the code in each module into Word and used "Find and replace" there to replace the code in all places.

In Word, "^p" works as paragrapgh break in the "Find what" box.